# Why is the number of Processes or threads part of the semantics of a concurrent program but only of secondary interest in a parallel one?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am really struggling to formulate a good concept for this one. Is it along the lines of the idea that a Parallel program will execute truly independently without relying on another thread/process? I am also struggling to issues parallelism adds to sequential programming and what issues concurrency adds to parallelism?

My ideas so far are that parallelism creates issues with sequential programming because it requires a different mindset, therefore perhaps programs should be written in the first place to not be inherently reliant on the order of operations.

I fail to see major issues concurrency adds to parallelism? Any clarification or explanation on these concepts is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I would say the number of processes or threads are part of the semantic of Parallelism, rather than concurrency. You can achieve concurrency with just a single multithreaded CPU, but to achieve parallelism you must by definition have 2 or more threads running simultaneously, on two separate CPU's or one hyperthreaded CPU.